# Set page content text to full width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to modify MDN page (eg: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) to make the content stretch to full width for printing. However I searched and tried multiple methods but none of them works, please help, thanks!

[image]

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: Hi Manish you can check the image I set `margin/width/padding/text-align`.

Comment: I see it, but i can't see the parent div or your site html structure..

Comment: Content not stretch to full width, because max-width is set in p   ` .text-content p{max-width: 42rem;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove [max-width style](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16VX9.png)

```
.text-content p {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    /* max-width: 42rem; */
```